# why select() always return 0 after the first timeout

Tags: c, linux, sockets

I have a problem about select function when I worked on a Linux socket program. The select function worked fine as the man page says if the client connected the server side in the time interval configured by the server. If the timeout happened, the select function will return 0 forever.  At that time, I debug the client and find the client had connected to the server. But the select function still return 0. I have search this problem but found none helpful. Could someone know why select did like that? My linux version is RHEL5.4. Thank you for your help.

The code is illustrated below.

```
static const int maxLog = 10000;

int main()
{
    int servSock;
    signal(SIGPIPE, SIG_IGN);
    if((servSock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0 )
    {
        printf("socket create fail\n");
        exit(-1);   
    }
    int val = 1;
    if(setsockopt(servSock, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &val, sizeof(val))<0)
    {
        DieWithUserMessage("setsockopt error");
    }

    struct sockaddr_in serverAddr;
    memset(&serverAddr, 0, sizeof(serverAddr));
    serverAddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverAddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htonl(INADDR_ANY);
    serverAddr.sin_port = htons(22000);

    if(bind(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &serverAddr, 
                sizeof(serverAddr)) < 0)
    {
        printf("socket bind  fail\n");
        exit(-1);   
    }

    if(listen(servSock, maxLog) < 0)
    {
        printf("listen failed\n");
        exit(-1);
    }   

    fd_set read_set;
    FD_ZERO(&read_set);
    FD_SET(servSock, &read_set);
    int maxfd1 = servSock + 1; 
    std::set<int> fd_readset;

    for(;;){    
        struct timeval tv;
        tv.tv_sec = 5;
        int ret = select(maxfd1, &read_set, NULL, NULL, tv);       
        if(ret == 0)
            continue;

        if(ret < 0)
            DieWithUserMessage("select error");

        if(FD_ISSET(servSock, &read_set))
        {
            struct sockaddr_in clntAddr;
            socklen_t clntAddrlen = sizeof(clntAddr);
            int clntSock = accept(servSock, (struct sockaddr *) &clntAddr, &clntAddrlen);
            if(clntSock < 0)
            {
                printf("accept failed()");
                exit(-1);
            }   

            maxfd1 = 1 +  (servSock>=clntSock? servSock:clntSock);
            FD_SET(clntSock, &read_set );
            fd_readset.insert(clntSock); 
         }

    } 
}
```

Comment: general advise: use poll() instead of select().

Comment: You must use `&tv` instead of `tv` in `select`

Answer (score 23):

The ['`select()`'](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/select.html) function is frustrating to use; you have to set up its arguments each time before you call it because it modifies them.  What you are seeing is a demonstration of what happens if you don't set up the fd_set(s) each time around the loop.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I reset the fs_set at the begin of the loop as you suggest and it works fine now.

Answer (score 4):

The same effect seems to happen if you don't reset the timeval struct before each call to select.

Comment: POSIX says that the `select()` function may modify the timeout paramter.  Presumably, if you're on a system that does modify it, its modified value records the time left until the timeout would expire, which is zero if the timeout did expire, and therefore after the first iteration the call degenerates into a poll because the zeroed timeout means 'return immediately' instead of 'wait if necessary'.

Answer (score 3):

You have the right answer already - re-init the `fd_set`s before each call to `select(2)`.

I would like to point you to a better alternative - Linux provides [`epoll(4)`](http://linux.die.net/man/4/epoll) facility. While it's not standard, it's much more convenient since you need to setup the events you wait for only once. The kernel manages the file descriptor event tables for you, so it's much more efficient. `epoll` also provides *edge-triggered* functionality, where only a change in state on a descriptor is signaled.

For completeness - BSDs provide [`kqueue(2)`](http://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=kqueue&sektion=2), Solaris has [`/dev/poll`](http://developers.sun.com/solaris/articles/polling_efficient.html).

One more thing: your code has a well known race condition between a client and the server. Take a look at [Stevens UnP: Nonblocking `accept`](http://books.google.com/books?id=ptSC4LpwGA0C&pg=PA461&dq=stevens+unp&hl=en&ei=cCZLTK6aAsKC8gan68Q1&sa=X&oi=book_result&ct=result&resnum=6&ved=0CD0Q6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: `poll` is standardized in POSIX.

Comment: But it's not any better then `select`.

Answer (score 1):

You have to fill your FD_SET at each iteration. The best way to do so is to maintain a collection of your FDs somewhere and put the one that you need for the select call in a temporary FD_SET.

If you need to handle a lot of clients, you might have to change the FD_SETSIZE (in `/usr/include/sys/select.h`) macro.

Happy network programming :)

Answer (score 1):

I've got the same trouble in my similar codes. I followed the suggestion of doing initialization each time before calling select() and it works. In codes at this case, just bringing the two lines into loop will make it work.

```
FD_ZERO(&read_set);
FD_SET(servSock, &read_set);
```